# Oracle SQL Return Count of Primary key from 2 different columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

**Tables**
ARMASTER = Customer Information
ORDERHEAD = Sales order information (Ship to, bill to)

Hey everyone! I'm still quite new to SQL and I do belive I'm picking it up fairly quick.  I have been racking my brain on this for a few hours now and have asked around the office and nobody seems to have a solution.

I'm trying to identify how many times a customer account has been used as a SHIP TO location & a BILL TO location.

```
SELECT ARMASTER.CUSTOMER,
   ARMASTER.DIVISION,
   ARMASTER.STATUS,
   ARMASTER.CUHEAD AS "MASTER",
   COUNT (ORDERHEAD.BILLTO) AS "COUNT_BILL",
   COUNT (ORDERHEAD.SHIPTO) AS "COUNT_SHIP"

FROM ARMASTER

LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERHEAD
 ON ARMASTER.CUSTOMER = ORDERHEAD.BILLTO
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERHEAD
 ON ARMASTER.CUSTOMER = ORDERHEAD.SHIPTO

GROUP BY ARMASTER.CUSTOMER,
         ARMASTER.DIVISION,
         ARMASTER.STATUS,
         ARMASTER.CUHEAD
```

And I'm not even remotley getting what I should be getting. However, when I remove one of my joins the count is exactly what it should be for either 1 or the other of them.

Any guidance would be muchly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `And I'm not even remotley getting what I should be getting` ... but what are you getting?  Can you at least show us some sample data?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will be sure to start putting examples into my questions right from the get go.  Is it easier as a file or within the window?

Comment: Just show a few sample records from each of the two tables along with your expected output.

Comment: I will do that in the future - thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: you left-join 1 table twice, but give no aliases for joins, so count does not work on desired table data

Comment: Thats another good point, would that run any faster than the subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can also work

```
    SELECT CUSTOMER,
       DIVISION,
       STATUS,
       CUHEAD AS "MASTER",
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ORDERHEAD WHERE SHIPTO = ARMASTER.CUSTOMER ) AS "COUNT_BILL",
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ORDERHEAD WHERE BILLTO = ARMASTER.CUSTOMER ) AS "COUNT_SHIP"
FROM ARMASTER
```

Comment: Jorge this is bang on and did the trick! Thank you for your help! And thank you to the community for getting back so quickly!